# How to detect change in a variable?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a variable in global scope that I need to check periodically for changes. This is how I would do it in simple JS:

```
    let currentValue, oldValue;

    setInterval(()=>{
       if(currentValue != oldValue){
          doSomething();
       }
    }, 1000)
```

How is it done using `Observables`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Observable.interval(1000)
    .map(() => currentValue)
    .distinctUntilChanged();
```

---

Or you can optionally give a comparator-function:

```
Observable.interval(1000)
    .map(() => currentValue)
    .distinctUntilChanged((oldValue, newValue) => <return true if equal>);
```